# Why a update of .NET targets triggers a "Activate Deploy"?

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows

I am working on small .NET MAUI app. So i used the MAUI Accelerator for bootstrapping the new project.
The default targets are Min: 10.0.17763.0 Max: 10.0.19041.0. But if i'm upgrading that Max target to 10.0.20348.0 or higher the build breaks, and i'm getting the information, that i have to set the deployment flag. But it is already set. And this error just is triggered by choosing a higher version. But why this is so? And how i can use higher versions without any error?

I tried out different targets and just a higher version as 10.0.20348.0 triggers that error.